# SSRS Report Viewer using Remote Processing (Multi Select Parameter Issue)

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, multi-select

Would REALLY appreciate help on this one.
I want to display a SSRS reportviewer (VS2005) control in my ASPNET (2.0) page.
I want to use report processing.
It works fine for ordinary parameters in the reportviewer but acts strange for multi select parameters. If I click a multiselect parameter, I can see the list flash for a second and then disappear. It does this each time I click it.

Anyone have a solution to stop this flash and disappearance that would allow me to pick from a selection of parameter.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this, I'd really appreciate the help.
Best Regards,
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and just want to share.
It was a simple problem of not being compatible with IE9.
When I turned on IE8 compatibility it worked.